# Unicity of the projection on a closed convex subset of $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, projection

The original problem (not full) statement is the following :

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{B},\mu)$ a measured space and $p>1$ and let $C$ be a closed convex subset of $L^p$.
>
> For $u\in L^p$ let $d_u:=\inf\{\|\phi-u\ \|, \phi \in C\}$
>
> Through some questions, the problem shows the existence of a $\phi \in C$ such that $\|\phi-u\ \|=d_u$.

The problem I have is with unicity. I read somewhere on MSE that *the $L^p$ norm is strictly convex*, which implies unicity.

As far as I know, **no norm is strictly convex**, so the previous affirmation might be wrong so how could we deal with unicity.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space

Comment: is $p=\infty$ possible? Because i think then the solution is not unique

Comment: Small remark on the jargon: One usually speaks about "uniqueness" and not "unicity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

For $p\in(1,\infty)$, assume there are two different solutions $\phi,\psi\in C$.
Then, by convexity of the norm, one can show that $(\phi+\psi)/2$ is closer to $u$ than $\phi$ or $\psi$.

In order to show the last part, you have to use the fact that for real numbers $a,b$ it holds that
$$
| (a+b)/2 | ^p = (|a|^p+|b|^p)/2
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
a = b.
$$